# Tag merge feedback requested: file-browser and file-management tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Izzy recently noticed that our community currently has a [file-browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-browser) tag (1 question) and a [file-management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-management) tag (395 questions).

Would the community like to merge [file-browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-browser) into [file-management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-management) and create a tag synonym?